# How to detect and remove newline character within a column in a csv file?

Tags: awk, perl, r

I have a large (2 Million rows) `csv` file exported from a `SQL Server` database. I don't have access to the database, and there's some newline character within a column, which makes it difficult to process in `R`.

Sample data like this:

```
playerID,yearID,gameNum,gameID,teamID,lgID,GP,startingPos
gomezle01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,1
ferreri01,1933,0,ALS193307060,BOS,AL,1,2
gehrilo01,1933,0
,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,3
gehrich01,1933,0,ALS193307060,DET,AL,1,4
dykesji01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,5
cronijo01,1933,0,ALS193307060
,WS1,AL,1,6
chapmbe01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,7
simmoal01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,8
ruthba01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,9
```

In above sample data, some lines breaks into two lines. How to clean it up?

**Update**

1. The csv file was generated on Microsoft platform. So the line ending is `^m`. I made up the sample data on Linux - ended in `\n`. It's my bad, I didn't make it clear. But I guess I can substitute `\n` with `\r\n`.
2. The line break doesn't always appear before a comma, it appears randomly even within a field like

.

```
Bill 
Gates.
```

**Solved**

Step 1: Remove `^M` in the middle of line:

```
perl -pe 's/\r(?!\n)//g'
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081465/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-in-the-middle-of-a-line

Step 2: Substitute `\n,` with `,` (See @jimmij 's answer below.)

```
perl -p00e 's/\n,/,/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perl` to the rescue:

```
$ perl -p00e 's/\n,/,/g' file
playerID,yearID,gameNum,gameID,teamID,lgID,GP,startingPos
gomezle01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,1
ferreri01,1933,0,ALS193307060,BOS,AL,1,2
gehrilo01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,3
gehrich01,1933,0,ALS193307060,DET,AL,1,4
dykesji01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,5
cronijo01,1933,0,ALS193307060,WS1,AL,1,6
chapmbe01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,7
simmoal01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,8
ruthba01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,9
```

I assumed here, that the split is always just before comma `,`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The newline character was generated on Microsoft  platform, so it should be carriage return. `^M` or `\r\n`. I didn't make it clear, my bad. (I made the data sample on Linux.)   No. The split is not always before comma, it even appears within a field like `Bill \r\n Gates`. I know this is really stupid. Data cleaning is always frustrated.

Comment: The problem solved by first remove all the `^M` in the middle of the line, and then using your perl code. The `00` option is not so clear, can you explain it briefly? What does a paragraph mean?

Comment: @Nick You can read about `0` nuances in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192485/how-exactly-does-perls-0-option-work . In fact in this case single `0` should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
playerID,yearID,gameNum,gameID,teamID,lgID,GP,startingPos
gomezle01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,1
ferreri01,1933,0,ALS193307060,BOS,AL,1,2
gehrilo01,1933,0
,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,3
gehrich01,1933,0,ALS193307060,DET,AL,1,4
dykesji01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,5
cronijo01,1933,0,ALS193307060
,WS1,AL,1,6
chapmbe01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,7
simmoal01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,8
ruthba01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,9
Bill
Gates,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,9
```

This puts the lines back together:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{printf "%s",$0; gsub(/[^,]/,""); nlast=n=length($0); next;} nlast==n{printf "\n";nlast=0} {printf "%s",$0; gsub(/[^,]/,""); nlast+=length($0)} END{print ""}' file
playerID,yearID,gameNum,gameID,teamID,lgID,GP,startingPos
gomezle01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,1
ferreri01,1933,0,ALS193307060,BOS,AL,1,2
gehrilo01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,3
gehrich01,1933,0,ALS193307060,DET,AL,1,4
dykesji01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,5
cronijo01,1933,0,ALS193307060,WS1,AL,1,6
chapmbe01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,7
simmoal01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,8
ruthba01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,9
BillGates,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,9
```

The line-ending requirements are not clear to me. We could add code to handle it here.  Or, for greatest flexibility,  you can run the file through `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` as needed.

### Answer for first version of question

> I have a large (2 Million rows) csv file

This is a line-oriented solution that does not require reading the entire file into memory at once:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && !/^,/{printf "\n";} {printf "%s",$0} END{print ""}' file
playerID,yearID,gameNum,gameID,teamID,lgID,GP,startingPos
gomezle01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,1
ferreri01,1933,0,ALS193307060,BOS,AL,1,2
gehrilo01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,3
gehrich01,1933,0,ALS193307060,DET,AL,1,4
dykesji01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,5
cronijo01,1933,0,ALS193307060,WS1,AL,1,6
chapmbe01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,7
simmoal01,1933,0,ALS193307060,CHA,AL,1,8
ruthba01,1933,0,ALS193307060,NYA,AL,1,9
```

#### How it works

- `NR>1 && !/^,/{printf "\n";}`

  If we are not on the first line, `NR>1`, and the current line does not begin with a comma, `!/^,/`, print a newline.
- `{printf "%s",$0}`

  Print the current line without a newline.
- `END{print ""}`

  When we reach the end of the file, print one more newline to terminate the last line.