# How to replace a multi line code with sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

I have a large file which has special characters in it. There is a multi line code there, that I want to replace with `sed`.

This:

```
  text = "\
    ------                                                           ------\n\n\
    This message was automatically generated by email software\n\
    The delivery of your message has not been affected.\n\n\
    ------                                                           ------\n\n"
```

Needs to turn into this:

```
text = ""
```

I tried the following code, but no luck:

```
sed -i '/  text = "*/ {N; s/  text = .*affected.\./  text = ""/g}' /etc/exim.conf
```

It does not replace anything and does not display any error messages

I have been playing with it, but everything I try does not work.

Comment: Does it need to be `sed` or are you open to other tools? Can there be `"` inside the `text=` block? Can there be other cases of `text = ` in your file? Will there always be 4 lines of text or can there be more/less?

Comment: Preferably `sed`, or anything that does not require installation in a CentOS server. Out of the box tools

Comment: @terdon There are not other `text = ` in the folder, the out come needs to be `text = ""`. The files has 891 lines of code. SO, it needs te respect the other text.

Comment: do you want to overwrite the file or just modify the output?

Comment: @Moonstroke NO OVERWRITE. It just needs to replace the text - as seen in my question - to `text = ""`. As seen in my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -i~ -0777 -pe 's/text = "[^"]+"/text = ""/g' input-file
```

- `-i~` will edit the file "in place", leaving a backup copy
- `-0777` reads the whole file at once, not line by line

The substitution `s///` works similarly as in sed (i.e. it matches `text = "` followed by anything but double quotes many times up to a double quote), but in this case, it works on the whole file.

Answer (score 6):

You have to check the pattern space and keep pulling in the `N`ext line if it doesn't match e.g.

```
sed '/text = "/{              # if line matches text = "
:b                            # label b
$!N                           # pull in the next line (if not the last one)
/"$/!bb                       # if pattern space doesn't end with " go to label b
s/".*"/""/                    # else remove everything between the quotes
}' infile
```

with `gnu sed` you can write it as

```
sed '/text = "/{:b;$!N;/"$/!bb;s/".*"/""/}' infile
```

That's not very efficient though, better just select the range `/text = "/,/"/`, modify the first line and delete the rest:

```
sed '/text = "/,/"/{            # in this range
/text = "/!d                    # delete all lines not matching text = "
s/\\/"/                         # replace the backslash with quotes (this is only
}' infile                       # executed if the previous d wasn't executed)
```

again, with `gnu sed` you can write it as a one-liner:

```
sed '/text = "/,/"/{/text = "/!d;s/\\/"/}' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would do this in Perl. If we can assume that there are no `"` before the closing `"`, you can do:

```
perl -0pe 's/(text\s*=\s*)".*?"/$1""/s' file
```

The `-0` slurps the entire file, reading it into memory. The `-p` means "print every line (here, a "line" will be the entire file) after applying the script given by `-e`". The script itself is a simple substitution operator. It will capture the string `text` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters, an `=` and 0 or more whitespace again (`text\s*=\s*`) and save it as `$1`.  Then, it will replace the captured pattern as well as the shortest quoted string it finds with the pattern (`$1`) and `""`. The `s` flag makes `.` match newlines.

Comment: correction, `-00` reads in paragraphs, not the whole file ([ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)). If the text in quotes contains a blank line, then the regex will not match.

Comment: @glennjackman argh! [I always get those mixed up.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192485/22222). Which is why I actually double checked by adding an extra paragraph and running `perl -00ne 'print;exit'`. And I still put the wrong one in my answer! Thanks, fixed now.