# concatenate lines based on first char of next line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I am looking for away contact lines based on the next line. So far the only way I see is to create a shell script that will read line by line and will do something along these lines:

```
while read line
    if $line does not start with "," and $curr_line is empty 
        store line in curr_line
    if $line does not start with "," and $curr_line is not empty
        flush $curr_line to file
        store $line in $curr_line
    if $line starts with "," append to $curr_file, flush to file empty curr_line
done < file
```

So I am trying to understand if could be achieved with sed or even grep with redirection.
the rules of the file are simple. 
There is at max one and only one line starting with "," that needs to be appended to the previous line.

ex:

```
line0
line1
line2
,line3
line4
line5
,line6
line7
,line8
line9
line10
line11
```

The result file would be

```
line0
line1
line2,line3
line4
line5,line6
line7,line8
line9
line10
line11
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do:

```
awk -v ORS= '
  NR>1 && !/,/ {print "\n"}
  {print}
  END {if (NR) print "\n"}' < file
```

That is, only prints that newline character that delimits the previous line if the current one does not start with a `,`.

In any case, [I wouldn't use a `while read` loop](/q/169716).

Comment: Why not: `awk '/,/||NR==1{printf $0; next}{printf "\n"$0}' < file` ?

Comment: @ValentinB. you'd be missing the trailing newline. It would also have to be `/^,/` and `printf "%s", $0`.

Comment: Indeed, I messed up that simple regex haha. `printf $0` seems to work though without adopting the formating, don't know if it's "supposed" to.

Comment: @Valentin, the first argument is the format, you don't want to pass variable data to that. That would fail if it contains `%` characters.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, another bad practice to ban then !

Comment: @Valentin, yes. It's a lot worse in C or the `printf` shell builtin btw, you should really get used to never use external data as the format.

Answer (score 8):

This is a classic use-case for `sed`, as explained in [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/), **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "=".** (with the obvious modification of `,` for `=`)

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n,/,/;ta' -e 'P;D' file
line0
line1
line2,line3
line4
line5,line6
line7,line8
line9
line10
line11
```

Comment: Also [in the `sed` FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.26)

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is slurp the file and remove any newlines before commas:

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/\n,/,/g' file
line0
line1
line2,line3
line4
line5,line6
line7,line8
line9
line10
line11
```

Comment: `perl -0007` is for BEL delimited records. Use `perl -777` to slurp the whole file in, though any byte other than newline and `,` as the record delimiter would also work here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, I always get this confused. Personally, I tend to just use `-0pe` for slurping so I don't remember the canonical one.

Comment: (sorry, meant `-0777` above). Yes, it can be confusing. `-0` is for NUL delimited `-00` is for paragraph mode (I sometimes get confused between those two), `-0<octal-greater-than-0>` is to delimit on the corresponding byte, unless the number is greater than 255 (0377) in which case as it's not a valid byte value it slurps the whole file in.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OK, so unless the file actually contains `\0`, using `-0` to slurp should be fine, right? I've even asked [a question about this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192485/22222), it's really confusing the way the numbers swing back.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a *perfect* use case for `ex`.**

If you haven't heard of it, `ex` is the predecessor to `vi` and, like `vi`, it is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) and available essentially* everywhere.

`ex` is actually designed for file *editing*, but you can use it without saving changes as well.

---

### Print changes, do not save to file:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^,/-j!' %p | ex file.txt
```

### Make changes and save to file:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^,/-j!' x | ex file.txt
```

---

### Explanation:

I use the `printf` command as a wrapper for `ex` for scripted file edits.  This form has the advantage that on any failure (e.g. you pass a command that isn't a real command, or you try to address a line number that doesn't exist), the command simply exits (without saving any changes) rather than waiting for other input.

You can view the exact commands passed by `printf` to `ex` by running the `printf` command by itself:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^,/-j!' %p
g/^,/-j!
%p
```

Okay, what do those commands do?

Well, `g` is the "global" command, and it runs the following command on all lines in the "buffer" (file) which match the regex `^,` (start of line followed by a comma).

The command in this case is `-j!`.  The `-` is an address, and it means execute the following command on the *previous* line to the current line.  (In other words, on the lines *before* lines starting with a comma.)

`j` is for "join" and it joins the line with the following line.  The exclam (`!`) suppresses using a space character to separate the original line from the line joined to it.

`%` is an address meaning "the entire buffer," and `p` means to "print."

`x` means to save changes and exit.

As I said, it's a *perfect* example of a use case for `ex`.

---

<sub>*Except Windows.  :P</sub>

Comment: Downvoter please comment.  This answer does *exactly* what is requested and will work on any Unix or Linux system.